# Terminar um processo programaticamente

Tags: c#

Quero fazer um programa que apresente um `Task Manager` ao utilizador. Já tenho a restante lógica, mas como posso terminar um processo (*task kill*) com `C#`?

Comment: Isto lhe serve? https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 6):

Se quiser terminar um conjunto de processos que partilhem o mesmo nome:

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(string);
foreach(var p in processes)
    p.Kill();
```

O método [`.GetProcessesByName(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/z3w4xdc9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) devolve um `array` de `strings` com todos os processos cujo o nome contenha a `string` passada ao método. De seguida, basta iterar pelos processos encontrados e invocar o método [`.Kill()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Pode também terminar o processo por *ID* da seguinte forma:

```
Process p = Process.GetProcessById(int);
p.Kill();
```

O método `.Kill()` força a aplicação a terminar. **No entanto, tenha em atenção que o método é assíncrono, isto é, é enviado o sinal de terminar ao processo, mas o retorno do método não significa que o processo terminou.**

Para esperar pelo fim do processo faça o seguinte:

```
Process p = Process.GetProcessById(int);
p.Kill();
p.WaitForExit(); // bloqueia a execução ate que o processo termine
```

O método [`.WaitForExit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) bloqueia a execução do seu programa até que o processo termine.

A contrapartida é que o seu programa pode ficar parado durante um tempo indeterminado.

Para evitar essa situação pode ainda passar um inteiro para `.WaitForExit(int)`. Este inteiro será o tempo, em milissegundos, esperado para que o processo termine. Caso o tempo passe sem o processo terminar, o método retorna.

Assim, para confirmar que o processo saiu correctamente, verifique o valor de [`p.HasExited`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

O código a seguir encerra o processo com PID 9812, por exemplo:

```
Process p = Process.GetProcessById(9812);
p.Kill();
```